# Converting an Address into a Postcode

Tags: php, location, postal-code

So I am retrieving some location data from a form, and submits the form to a php script. I want it to be that people can type in an address, postcode, or place name, and it converts it into a postcode for processing.

How would I convert the place name into a postcode?

Comment: Worldwide, or only for a specific area/country?

Comment: By looking it up in a database. Also, don't expect a lot of help if you don't accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) Web Services.

An example query to look info by place names can be

http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch?placename=sydney&maxRows=10&username=demo